# How to construct a tuple of two from list

Tags: python

How to construct a list of tuple from a list.

Let a list data_set be

```
data_set = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Output I needed is

```
tuple_set = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

I am new to python, a little help 'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: take a minute for searching through SO - you'll find duplicates. After that, it's good to delete the current dupe

Comment: Combine `zip` with list slicing